# How to enable Sticky Session in WSO2 Elastic Load Balancer for Vaadin

Tags: wso2, load-balancing, vaadin, jsessionid

wso2 or vaadin people
I follow this guide to setup ELB for WSO2 Application Server
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ELB203/Setup+ELB+with+WSO2+Application+Server

The ELB works perfectly. However, My vaadin application show this error.

```
Cookies disabled

This application requires cookies to function.
Please enable cookies in your browser and click here to try again.
```

Vaadin related commit link.
http://dev.vaadin.com/changeset/11570/svn

It should be some problem related to session/cookie.

I am willing to provide more information if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the bug is fixed in wso2 svn trunk but not in lastest ELB/ESB. I get two JSESSIONID cookie, thats why passthrough proxy fails. Hope it helps someone.

See https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1659

Answer (score 0):

Can please you try to access your application bypassing WSO2 ELB and send us the http headers that are flowing through to the application (use TCPMon in between Client and your application) ?

FYI WSO2 ELB do preserve JSESSIONID cookie.